# Apple certificate expired/revoked: xCode error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain

I have been testing iOS app on the iPhone for a month. I accidentally deleted the certificate on the `iTunesConnect(Apple Developers website)`. But I again recreated the certificate + App ID identifiers.

I am now getting this error...

I however did change the name of the app around the same time.

> The certificate used to sign "AppleApp" has either expired or has been
>   revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the
>   application.

I have added/downloaded by going to `XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts` then 
I added Developers Login.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your certificate expire date:
xCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Detail -> found your certificate
and check your certificate expire that download new certificate on apple developer site.